# Polynomial long division - find the value of p and q

Tags: polynomials

When the polynomial $P(x)=4x^3+px^2+qx+1$ is divided by $x-1$, the remainder is -2. When $P(x)$ is divided by $(2x-1)$, the remainder is $\frac{13}{4}$.

Result of first division seems to be $4x^2+(p+4)x+(p+4+q)+\frac{p+4+q+1}{x-1}$, the second one gives $2x^2+\frac{2+p}{2}x+\frac{1+p+q}{2}+\frac{\frac{1+p+q}{2}}{2x-1}$.

So I have two equations, $p+4+q+1=-2$ and $\frac{1+p+q}{2}=\frac{13}{4}$. But this doesn't make any sense. If I try to put $p$ from the first one to the second one, I get $-3=\frac{13}{4}$...

I tried to do the divisions three times and I don't think there is a mistake, so do you have any idea where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your second division.

First step:
$$
(4x^3 + px^2 + qx + 1)/(2x - 1) = 2x^2 + ((p + 2)x^2 + qx + 1)/(2x - 1)
$$

Second step:
$$
((p + 2)x^2 + qx + 1)/(2x - 1) = \frac{p + 2}{2}x + ((q + \frac{p + 2}{2})x + 1)/(2x - 1)
$$

And $q + \frac{p + 2}{2} = \frac{p + 2q + 2}{2}$

Note the $2$ in front of $q$.

So you end up with two equations:
$$
p + q = -7 \\
p + 2q = 7
$$

And from here the problem is solvable ($p = -21$, $q = 14$).

Comment: We can eliminate fractions (and any errors that they cause),  e.g. see my answer.

Comment: I agree that those divisions make it easy to make mistakes (which was actually the reason for the question). But the method on itself is correct. Staying with this method showed the OP where his mistake was. The other answers are a reason why this forum is so valuable as they provide another insight into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use remainder theorem or Factor theorem.

> It states that the remainder of the division of a polynomial f(x) by a linear polynomial ${\displaystyle x-r}$ is equal to ${\displaystyle f(r).}$ In particular, ${\displaystyle x-r}$ is a divisor of 
>   f(x) if and only if, ${\displaystyle f(r)=0,}$ a property known as the factor theorem.

So, from this, you're given:

$P(1)=-2$ and $P(1/2)=13/4$

Can you take it from here now?

Answer (score 0):

By the *Remainder Theorem* $\,P(a) = P(x)\bmod x\!-\!a.\,$ So evaluating $P(x)$ at $a = 1,\,1/2\,$ yields $\,2\,$ linear equations for $p,q$. To avoid *errors* with fractions we can eliminate them by scaling by $4$, viz.

$\begin{align}
\!\!\!\bmod\ \  x-1\!:\qquad\qquad\ \ \ P(x) &= 4\,\color{#c00}x^3+p\color{#c00}x^2+q\color{#c00}x+1\\
\color{#c00}{x\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\ \ -2 \equiv P(1) &\equiv 4\,\color{#c00}1^3 + p\,\color{#c00}1^2 + q\,\color{#c00}1 + 1\, \equiv\, p+q+5\quad\ \ \iff\quad\ \ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid orange] { p+q = -7}
\end{align}$

$\begin{align} 
\!\!\!\bmod{\ 2x - 1}\!:\qquad\qquad 4 P(x) &= 2(\color{#c00}{2x})^3\!\!+p(\color{#c00}{2x})^2\!\! + 2q(\color{#c00}{2x})\!+\!4\\
\color{#c00}{2x\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,13 = 4P(\frac{1}2) &\equiv 2(\color{#c00}1)^3 +\ p(\color{#c00}1)^2 +\ 2q(\color{#c00}1)\ + 4\,\equiv\, p+2q+6\!\iff\! \bbox[5px,border:1px solid orange]{p+2q = 7}
\end{align}$